# How to use Styler.to_latex to output the column names and multi-index names in the same row?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I am trying to output the column names and multi-index names in the same row while exporting the table to latex.
Here is an example:

```
arrays = [
    np.array(["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"]),
    np.array(["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"]),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
df.index.names = ("alpha", "beta")
print(df.style.to_latex())
```

Currently, prints:

```
 &  & A & B & C & D \\
alpha & beta &  &  &  &  \\
```

But, I am looking to make it:

```
alpha & beta & A & B & C & D \\
```

One way is to reset the index, but that duplicates the values under `alpha` instead of using `\multirow`.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround could be to replace duplicated  values in `alpha` with empty string, and then convert to latex:

```
df = df.reset_index().sort_values('alpha')
df['alpha'] = df.alpha.where(~df.alpha.duplicated(), '')

df
  alpha beta         A         B         C         D
0   bar  one -0.798176  0.108303 -0.901825  0.642972
1        two  0.936514 -1.020388 -0.188727  1.191357
2   baz  one  0.543654  0.293224 -2.704428  0.533671
3        two -0.991421 -0.237080 -1.336688  0.819651
4   foo  one -0.152619 -0.639297  0.913966 -2.010235
5        two  1.692754  0.106209  0.547102  0.463772
6   qux  one -0.431927 -0.102342 -1.282117 -0.538493
7        two -0.095201  2.173642 -0.164405  0.640185

print(df.style.to_latex())
\begin{tabular}{lllrrrr}
 & alpha & beta & A & B & C & D \\
```